# What's the importance and usage of additional file opening modes(modes with additional '+' sign) in PHP?

Tags: php, file, file-io, file-handling

I'm a newbie to PHP.

I was going through the basic core concepts of PHP. **'File Handling'** is one of the basic and important concepts of PHP.

While studying this concept I come across various file opening modes available in PHP. Following is the description of each of these file opening modes :

```
Modes   Description
  r        Open a file for read only. File pointer starts at the beginning of the file
  w        Open a file for write only. Erases the contents of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist. File pointer starts at the beginning of the file
  a        Open a file for write only. The existing data in file is preserved. File pointer starts at the end of the file. Creates a new file if the file doesn't exist
  x        Creates a new file for write only. Returns FALSE and an error if file already exists
  r+       Open a file for read/write. File pointer starts at the beginning of the file
  w+       Open a file for read/write. Erases the contents of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist. File pointer starts at the beginning of the file
  a+       Open a file for read/write. The existing data in file is preserved. File pointer starts at the end of the file. Creates a new file if the file doesn't exist
  x+       Creates a new file for read/write. Returns FALSE and an error if file already exists
```

I was able to understood the purpose of first four file opening modes from above list(i.e. 'r', 'w', 'a' and 'x') but I'm not at all able to understand the purpose of additional file opening modes from above list(i.e. 'r+', 'w+', 'a+' and 'x+') as it has the same description as of first four file opening modes.

So my question is since the first four basic file opening modes are already available then why these additional file opening modes are required/defined? What's the purpose of using them and when to use the first four and when to use latter four while dealing with files?

Please help me by clearing my above doubt.
 If you could explain with some appropriate example it would be really great and helpful for me as well as other community members.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't see any difference between "read only/write only" and "read/write"?

Comment: Do we make any progress on this question ?

Answer (score 4):

In short the '+' means the file is opened for both reading and writing.

[From the PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'r'   Open for reading only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.
>
> 'r+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.
>
> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'w+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'x'   Create and open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file. If the file already exists, the fopen() call will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level E_WARNING. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. This is equivalent to specifying O_EXCL|O_CREAT flags for the underlying open(2) system call.
>
> 'x+'  Create and open for reading and writing; otherwise it has the same behavior as 'x'.
>
> 'c'   Open the file for writing only. If the file does not exist, it is created. If it exists, it is neither truncated (as opposed to 'w'), nor the call to this function fails (as is the case with 'x'). The file pointer is positioned on the beginning of the file. This may be useful if it's desired to get an advisory lock (see flock()) before attempting to modify the file, as using 'w' could truncate the file before the lock was obtained (if truncation is desired, ftruncate() can be used after the lock is requested).
>
> 'c+'  Open the file for reading and writing; otherwise it has the same behavior as 'c'.

Answer (score 2):

So let's go through all of these modes and see what they do:

- **Mode: r** With  the mode r you only can read a file which exists, means it doesn't create a file if it doesn't exists nor you can write into it:

  1. Trying to access a non-existent file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file does not exists 
     $h = fopen($filename, "r");
     ```

  This will result in an error:

  > Warning:  fopen(test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  Because the file doesn't exists and it doesn't get created.

  2. Trying to write into a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file does exists
     $h = fopen($filename, "r");
     fwrite($h, "TEST");
     fclose($h);
     ```

  This won't throw you any error, but `fwrite()` will return FALSE if you do: `var_dump(fwrite($h, "TEST"));`, because it can't write into a file with mode r.

  3. Trying to read a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file does exists
     $h = fopen($filename, "r");
     $content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
     fclose($h);

     print_r($content);
     ```

  The code will work fine and you will get the entire content from your file displayed.
- **Mode: r+** This mode is similar to the mode r, but it's a bit different and that is, that you can write into a file.

  1. Trying to write into a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file does exists
     $h = fopen($filename, "r+");
     fwrite($h, "TEST");
     fclose($h);
     ```

  Same code as before, but with the different, that `var_dump(fwrite($h, "TEST"));` will return the number of bytes it has written into the file (here `int(4)`).

  Also note, that it will overwrite the file, if you write something into it.   Otherwise mode r+ has the same behaviour as mode r with reading a file and opening a non existent file.
- **Mode: w** With this mode you can only write into a file, so you can't read it and if the file doesn't exist it tries to create the file. Also as with r+ if you write to a file it will overwrite everything in it.

  1. Trying to access a non-existent file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file does not exists 
     $h = fopen($filename, "w");
     fclose($h);
     ```

  So this code will just work fine and won't give you any errors. Since the file doesn't exist, it will just simply try to create it.

  2. Trying to write into a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file can exist or not, doesn't make a difference
     $h = fopen($filename, "w");
     fwrite($h, "TEST");
     fclose($h);
     ```

  This code will also work fine and it will write the content into your file. And as I said it will overwrite the file!

  3. Trying to read a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file can exist or not, doesn't make a difference
     $h = fopen($filename, "w");
     $content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
     fclose($h);

     print_r($content);
     ```

  This code will end up with a warning:

  > Warning:  fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0

  Because by accessing the file with the mode w the file will be truncated to zero length. So you can't read anything with fread(). (Also a bit more about this in the examples of mode w+)
- **Mode: w+** This mode is similar to the mode w with the difference, that you can also read the file.

  1. Trying to read a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; 
     $h = fopen($filename, "w+");
     fwrite($h, "TEST");
     fseek($h, 0); //See footnote 1
     $content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
     fclose($h);

     print_r($content);
     ```

  This code will just work fine and will print you: `TEST`.  Here it's the same as with mode w, that it will truncate the file to zero length, means after opening it you have to write something into it, then you can read it.

  <sub>Footnote: After opening the file it is at zero length, so you have to write something into it, that you can read something. But now it's so, that if you open the file, the file pointer will be at the start of the file. Then when you write something e.g. "XY" the pointer will be at 2, so if you try to read it you start from 2 -> And you read the file, so obviously there is no content, so you have to set the file pointer back to the beginning with fseek() to read the entire file.</sub>
- **Mode: a:** So with mode a you can append text to a file, but you can't read it. If a file doesn't exist it will try to create it.

  1. Trying to access a non-existent file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file does not exists 
     $h = fopen($filename, "a");
     fclose($h);
     ```

  This code will just behave like mode w. If the file doesn't exist it tries to create it.

  2. Trying to write into a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file can exist or not, doesn't make a difference
     $h = fopen($filename, "a");
     fwrite($h, "TEST");
     fclose($h);
     ```

  This code works similar to mode w, but with the difference, that if you already have something in your file it won't get overwritten.

  3. Trying to read a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; //file can exist or not, doesn't make a difference
     $h = fopen($filename, "a");
     $content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
     fclose($h);

     print_r($content);
     ```

  This will not end up like with mode w where you got a warning, because it doesn't overwrite the file while opening it. But fread() will also return FALSE, since you can't read the file with mode a.
- **Mode: a+** And this mode is similar to mode a, but with the difference, that you can also read the file.

  1. Trying to read a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt"; 
     $h = fopen($filename, "a+");
     $content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
     fclose($h);

     print_r($content);
     ```

  If the file has content in it you will be able to read it and you will get it as an output.
- **Mode: x** This mode is to create a file for writing. It will give you a warning if the file already exists.

  1. Trying to create file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt";  //file does not exists
     $h = fopen($filename, "x");
     ```

  This code will create the file with no problem. If it would already exist, you would get an error.

  2. Trying to read a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt";  //file does not exists
     $h = fopen($filename, "x");
     $content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
     fclose($h);
     ```

  This will have the same behaviour as mode w has here.

  3. Trying to write into a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt";  //file does not exists
     $h = fopen($filename, "x");
     fwrite($h, "TEST");
     fclose($h);
     ```

  this will also have the same behaviour as mode w has here and you will be able to write into the file.
- **Mode: x+** And as you can already guess it if you see the pattern from the other modes, the + allows also reading from the file.

  1. Trying to read a file:

     ```
     $filename = "test.txt";  //file does not exists
     $h = fopen($filename, "x+");
     fwrite($h, "TEST");
     fseek($h, 0); //See the footnote on mode w+
     $content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
     fclose($h);
     ```

  Reading will just work fine as expected.

So as you can see these modes are all different and do/allow different things. So that's why they exist and depending what you need you can choose a mode to open a file.

---

I hope these examples shows you clearly what the differences are between all these modes. If you want to read more about the modes and the functions see the manual:

- [`fopen()` (Includes a nice overview with all the different modes)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- [`fwrite()` (To write into a file)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)
- [`fread()` (To read a file)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)
- [`fseek()` (To set the file pointer)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)
- [`fclose()` (To close a file)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)